# RuntimeError: [enforce fail at CPUAllocator.cpp:65] . DefaultCPUAllocator: can't allocate memory

Tags: python, ocr, raspberry-pi3, torch, torchvision

This is the python script i'm trying to run:

```
import easyocr 
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('test.jpg')
print(result)
```

I tried it on my pc and it works.
However, when trying it on Raspberry  Pi it doesn't.
I am using a virtual environment.

- numpy version: 1.20.2
- easyocr version: 1.3.0.1
- torch version: 1.7.0a0+e85d494
- Torchvision version:0.8.0a0+45f960c
- Python version: 3.7.3

This is the what I get when I run it through the terminal:

```
CUDA not available - defaulting to CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocr.py", line 3, in <module>
    result = reader.readtext('test.jpg')
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyocr/easyocr.py", line 379, in readtext
    add_margin, False)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyocr/easyocr.py", line 273, in detect
    False, self.device, optimal_num_chars)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyocr/detection.py", line 81, in get_textbox
    bboxes, polys = test_net(canvas_size, mag_ratio, detector, image, text_threshold, link_threshold, low_text, poly, device, estimate_num_chars)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyocr/detection.py", line 38, in test_net
    y, feature = net(x)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyocr/craft.py", line 60, in forward
    sources = self.basenet(x)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyocr/model/modules.py", line 61, in forward
    h = self.slice1(X)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 117, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 423, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight)
  File "/home/pi/johara/ocri/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 420, in _conv_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: [enforce fail at CPUAllocator.cpp:65] . DefaultCPUAllocator: can't allocate memory: you tried to allocate 1519386624 bytes. Error code 12 (Cannot allocate memory)
```

Comment: I assume because raspebrry pi does not have 1.5 gb of the memory it needs to allocate, whereas Your pc has.